# ArangoDB AQL Query Exception in Java

Tags: arangodb

I am executing below AQL query in java for ArangoDB to get total no of descendants of particular node. Here's code for this.

```
        String nodeUserid = nodeuserid.getText().trim();
        Map<String, Object> bindVars = new MapBuilder().put("nodeid", nodeUserid).get();
        CursorResult cs = arangoDriver.executeAqlQuery("LET x = (FOR v IN 1..1000 OUTBOUND @nodeid GRAPH 'TempPeoplesApp' "
                + " RETURN v.x)"
                + " RETURN SUM(x)", bindVars, null,null);

        int count = cs.getCount();
```

But at runtime it gives an exception stated below,

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1768)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at com.arangodb.entity.EntityDeserializers$CursorEntityDeserializer.getResultObjects(EntityDeserializers.java:686)
    at com.arangodb.entity.EntityDeserializers$CursorEntityDeserializer.deserialize(EntityDeserializers.java:647)
    at com.arangodb.entity.EntityDeserializers$CursorEntityDeserializer.deserialize(EntityDeserializers.java:621)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:861)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:826)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
    at com.arangodb.entity.EntityFactory.createEntity(EntityFactory.java:163)
    at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntityImpl(BaseArangoDriver.java:367)
    at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntityWithFallback(BaseArangoDriver.java:259)
    at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntity(BaseArangoDriver.java:236)
    at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntity(BaseArangoDriver.java:311)
    at com.arangodb.impl.InternalCursorDriverImpl.executeCursorEntityQuery(InternalCursorDriverImpl.java:81)
    at com.arangodb.impl.InternalCursorDriverImpl.executeAqlQuery(InternalCursorDriverImpl.java:148)
    at com.arangodb.ArangoDriver.executeAqlQuery(ArangoDriver.java:2144)
    at peoplesapptree.TreeCreationController.displayDescendents(TreeCreationController.java:169)
    ... 57 more
```

It gives an exception while executing arangoDriver.executeAqlQuery method. So whats wrong in this query? Can anyone suggest? I am new to ArangoDB

Thanks,
Mayank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Version of ArangoDB and the ArangoDB-Java-Driver do you use?

The method `executeAqlQuery` need to know which type in CursorResult you expect. It's the last parameter. In your case, you want probably an Integer for your sum in the Aql.

```
        String nodeUserid = nodeuserid.getText().trim();
        Map<String, Object> bindVars = new MapBuilder().put("nodeid", nodeUserid).get();
        CursorResult<Integer> cs = arangoDriver.executeAqlQuery(
            "LET x = (FOR v IN 1..1000 OUTBOUND @nodeid GRAPH 'TempPeoplesApp' " + " RETURN v.x)" + " RETURN SUM(x)",
            bindVars, null, Integer.class);

        Integer sum = cs.getUniqueResult();
```

#### getCount() vs getFullCount() vs getUniqueResult()

`getCount()` returns the total number of results. `getFullCount()` returns the total number of resulst with (aql)limit clause. In your case your aql returns only 1 result, the sum. A aql can return a list of results. When you have only 1 result you can get it with `getUniqueResult`, when you have n results use the method `iterator()` or `asList()` and iterate over it.

The method `executeAqlQuery` supports wrapper classes for all primitive Types, Map, List and on uniqe aql result Java-Beans.

Comment: Hi mpv, Thanks for pointing out in right direction. I was using ArangoDB version 3.0.2 version and java driver version 2.4 version. Now i replaced java driver with latest version 3.0.0 version. and had to change code like this,  
            CursorResult cs = arangoDriver.executeAqlQuery("LET x = (FOR v IN 1..1000 OUTBOUND @nodeid GRAPH 'TempPeoplesApp' "
                    + " RETURN v.x)"
                    + " RETURN SUM(x)", bindVars, null,null);

 While executing this code, i get NullPointerException at the same line. Could you give some hint?

Comment: can you update the stack output in your question plz?

Comment: Thanks it works. What's the difference between getCount(),getFullCount() and getUniqueResult() methods of CursorResult and by the way does it support all wrapper classes of java in executeAqlQuery() method as argument.